# Angular JS App using REST API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

I'm currently trying to intergrate a login API with my angular JS app for authentication.

This is my current login function:

```
  var $promise = $http.post(API + '/login', {
      username: name,
      password: pw
  });

  $promise.then(function(msg){
    if(msg.data.success == true){
      resolve('Login success.');
    }else{
      reject('Login Failed.');
    }
  });
```

It's successfully returning when successful, however when I try to GET the settings from the user using the API I'm getting an error for unauthorization.

This is my GET request:

```
   $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: API + '/account/settings',
       withCredentials: true
   }).then(function successCallback(response) {
       // SUCCESS
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
       // ERROR
   });
```

It's really, really puzzling me. I can use Postman to make the API call to login and then GET from the settings, but can't for the life of me get this working.

These are my response headers from the LOGIN request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8100
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:171
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 20 Dec 2016 21:30:05 GMT
ETag:W/"ab-vCrnhzn26fE4borN6cmpAw"
set-cookie:connect.sid=s%3A1EF4OfHQ2uYb750QvccZB4pnNCyTsAfd.ISmVn3vE5jXjEwmLbtsQK4O339%2Fw74K3Y613f4%2FcTKE; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary:Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: When you get the result back from that login API, do you see any authorization header being added to the response, and if so have you added that to the next request header?

Comment: Hey @YaserAdelMehraban, I'm getting a body response back with the success and then I get the following back in the response headers:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100
Vary: Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 171
ETag: W/"ab-vCrnhzn26fE4borN6cmpAw"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AEtJZCOqfGu4UqZnLGDIfIZXjAYKUQx12.EqyopERh6bEgIawPrtY5Jwqe7HqB5FFBgefqUy%2BSsrk; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Tue, 20 Dec 2016 21:20:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Can you update your post with the response (hard to read in comments). Not sure what kind of server you are using for that API but usually you will need an authorization header which is coming from a successful login, added to the request, take a look at here: http://oskarhane.com/add-authorization-header-to-angularjs-http/

Comment: Hey @YaserAdelMehraban, that's updated now. I'm using Drywall on Node and the REST API that is in that. It shouldn't be an issue with the API if I can login successfully with Postman though should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced back the server you are using and found a project called ngFrame which consumes almost all of the API's of `Drywall`, there are samples of authentication as well there.

There is a function called setAuthHeader in the source you can take a look at:

```
function setAuthHeader(user) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = user.authHeader
}
```

The use which is passed in here is coming from the response of the post to login:

```
$http.post('/api/login', user).success(function(user) {});
```

Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/Silom/ngFrame) page.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently using this: https://github.com/arthurkao/angular-drywall which is the angular version of Drywall which is all setup and working. So are you saying that my login post is wrong? or the response back isn't right?

Comment: Yap if you take a look at security.js there is nowhere that sets authentication header. Not even in the interceptor they are using for retry unauthorized-server

Comment: Damn, so it's nothing I can simply edit to get working?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the ngFrame and see if you can find an example with that, then search for login issues with angular-drywall

Comment: Well it's actually working now, I've not changed anything. I'm very confused. Thanks for your help though dude, greatly appreciated.